# How would I be able to find out the right font size for the 2nd container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on this project. Basically, I have 2 containers both of which have 2 different widths and heights. My goal is to find the right font-size for the 2nd container in relative to 1st container.

In both of these containers, they contain exactly similar words depending on the user input. I have also implemented the "word-break" property in both of them. If the 1st container starts breaking the words when reaching the end of a line, I want the 2nd container to do exactly the same.

How would I solve this in Javascript or Jquery?

[image]

Comment: One idea is to calculate the `font-size` based on the ratio of widths: `x = 51 * (510 / 612) = 42.5`. Is this just a one-time calculation or does it need to be calculated dynamically/responsively?

Comment: Yes, it need to be calculated dynamically.

Comment: you can try to add another container inside the second containers that match the dimensions of the first one, that way the line break will be synchronous I think

Comment: I've tried to play around with the font-size on the second container and it seems that "75-76px" is the key number. But I want to do it dynamically

Comment: @ Wael Fadhel that's a good idea, but unfortunately, I can't do that because the container itself is a background image. It will ruin the layout.

Comment: @PhilGreene you can set the background color of the newly added container to transparent, that way it won't affect the second container background image

Comment: Yes, but the thing is they both have different widths and heights. If I do as you suggested, the font-size on the 2nd image would look smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to calculate `font-size` based on the radio of widths:

```
x = originalFontSize * (newWidth / originalWidth)
  = 51 * (510 / 612)
  = 42.5
```

Here's a demonstration:

```js
let firstBox = document.getElementById('one');
let firstSize = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(firstBox, null).getPropertyValue('font-size'));
let els = document.getElementsByClassName('resize');

Array.from(els).forEach((el) => {
  let thisSize = firstSize * (el.clientWidth / firstBox.clientWidth);
  el.style.fontSize = thisSize + "px";
});
```

```css
div {
  word-break: break-all;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#one {
  width: 320px;
  font-size: 18px
}
#two {
  width: 280px;
}
#three {
  width: 210px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus.
</div>
<div id="two" class="resize">
  Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus.
</div>
<div id="three" class="resize">
  Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is just what I am looking for.

Comment: Just tried It, it works perfectly!! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any CSS preprocessors? You can achieve what you want by making a function to return a value in vw, which can be calculated using a rule of three. Here's what i used a few months ago, using Stylus.

```
m_rof(value)
    ((value / 375) * 100)vw
```

Basically, here's what it does and how it works.

In the small portrait viewport (375px), defined within the visual design, i can keep the same ratio in the 414 viewport. If the font is like, 12 pixels on the 375 viewport, it will be around 14px in the 414 viewport.

You can use this to assure the text size will always fit the viewport **OR** you can set the font-size using [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fontsize) to base the size on the container.